# How can I format all the cells in CSV to text, when exporting using Sheet.js package?

Tags: javascript

I'm exporting to a csv file using sheet.js npm module. After exporting, if I enter a number that has a length more than 10 (677894567897), then it shows like 6.77895E+11. So when reading, it will be read as 6.77895E+11. I want to format all the cells in the csv export to text. How can I do this using this sheet.js npm module?

[image]